# Websites displaying as mobile on all browsers in MacOS

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser

For some reason, numerous websites started displaying as mobile on my MacOS machine today, in all browsers, even browsers I never use like Safari. The agent header I'm seeing in Chrome is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
```

Any ideas about what's going on and how to correct it?

Comment: Can you please add the full Agent header to the question? Also, does it only happen on sites you've visited before, or also on sites you've never been yet?

Comment: I added an agent header to the post. I'm seeing this on sites I've never visited in browsers I've never used, like Safari.

Comment: I was able to correct things in Safari by wiping the cache. Wiping the cache in Chrome and Firefox does not fix things.

Comment: When did this start happening? Have you recently installed any software/extensions/plugins?